# jQuery 動的に読み込んだDOM要素の表示完了時にjQueryプラグインを適用したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

動的に読み込んだ要素にjQueryプラグインを適用したいです。

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

上記の中に`<a class='tooltip' href=...>link</a>`を動的に読み込んで追加し、そこにプラグインを適用させたいのですが、うまくいきません。

```
$(function(){
  $("div#content").on("ready","a",function(){
    //イベントが発生しないためこの中は実行されない
    $("a.tooltip").tooltip();
  });
});
```

`click`イベントの場合は動作しますが、読み込み完了がうまく出来ません。
御教示のほどお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

雑に言うと[jQuery.ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)はピュアjsでいうところの[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)イベントにあたるタイミングで発火するものです→[参考](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)。つまりページ読み込み時のタイミングですから、今回のようにある要素に子要素が追加されたとき、などの処理とは異なります。
この場合は、たとえば[jquery - on append() do something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167085/on-append-do-something)で紹介されている方法などを用いて**要素の追加時に発火するイベントを設定する**か、`動的に読み込んで追加`する処理のあとに、プラグインを適用する処理をおけばいいのではないでしょうか。
応用的に様々な手段で要素が追加されることを考えると、私は前者がいいと思いますので、例では[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)を用いた要素の監視により、追加時にプラグインの適用処理をしています。

```js
// 子要素の追加を監視
var plugin = function (el) {
  // dummy
  el.textContent += ':plugin applied.';
};
var callback = function (e) {
  // 追加されたノードはe[0].addedNodesに入っている
  var added = e[0].addedNodes;
  // プラグイン適用
  for (var i = 0; i < added.length; i++) {
    plugin(added[i]);
  }
};
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe($('#container')[0], {childList: true});

// 要素を動的に追加
$("#append").click(function (e) {
  $("#container").append('<div>Child</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="append">Append Child</button>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！頂いたコードをみるとデザインパターンのObserverパターンですね。追加ノードを通知する仕組みがあったというのは知りませんでした。大変参考になりました。早速確認してみたいと思います。

Comment: さきほど教えて頂いたMutationObserverクラスを使ってテストしてみました。これならDOMツリーに何らかの変化が発生するプラグインなら、プラグインのコードを書き換えないでも発火タイミングを取り出せてとても便利です。ありがとうございました。