# SPAで動的に挿入されるDOMに対する$(DOMElement).on('load',...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

SPAでページ遷移時に動的に挿入されるDOMElementに対して`$(DOMElement).on('load',func)`のような、特定のDOMのロード時に処理を行うにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。

例えば、
http://example.xxx/hoge ページにある
http://example.xxx/fuga のリンクをクリックすると/fugaに遷移し、
遷移時に挿入された`<div id="piyo"></div>`という要素のロード時に処理を行いたいです。

chromeの拡張機能で処理を行う制限があります。jQueryを使用しなくても良いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参考→ http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27279/jquery-%E5%8B%95%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0dom%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%A0%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E5%AE%8C%E4%BA%86%E6%99%82%E3%81%ABjquery%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E9%81%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MutationObserverを使うとどうでしょうか。
DOMの変更を監視できるので、対象のDOM要素がロードされる = document.getElementById()で取得できるという風に考えると、目的を達成できるかと。

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
  var elm = document.getElementById("piyo");
  if (elm) {
    // 対象の要素が読み込まれたので、ここで好きなことを行う
    // これ以上監視を続けない場合は、observer.disconnect()する
  }
});

observer.observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

詳しくはドキュメントなどを参照すると良いでしょう。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。アリですね！パフォーマンスが気になりますが、そこら辺は試して計測してみようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

pushStateを利用しているSPAなら、popstateイベントを監視することで遷移が分かります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。残念ながらpushStateは使われていない類のWebページでした。。