# jQueryで生成した要素に対してaddClasssでアニメーションが効かない

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

もともと、html側で要素をつくった場合はうまくいきます。

```
[css]

    .box{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:tomato;
        transition: 3s;
    }

    .blue{
        background:skyblue;
    }





    [js]

    $(function(){
        //要素をつくる
        var box = $('<div class="box">');

        //表示する
        $('body').append(box);
        box.addClass('blue');//アニメーション

    });
```

Comment: アニメーションとはどう言ったアニメーションをどうやって実装して行っているのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！背景色をtomato→skyblueにしたいです！

Comment: あぁ、そういうことですね。`backgroud`が`class`でスタイル指定が重複しているから反映されないと言うことですね。ブラウザはなんでしょうか？Win7のChromeでは変わりますが……

Comment: win 7のchromeです

Comment: もしかして、今の状態でも色は変わってるけどジワジワ変わって欲しいとか？

Comment: そうです、transition:3sをつkて、アニメーションにしています。もともとhtmlに<div class="box">があらかじめ書かれているときは、うまくいくのですが、js内でdiv要素を生成すると初めから青になった状態で表示されます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)で1フレーム遅らせることで可能です。

```js
    $(function(){
        //要素をつくる
        var box = $('<div class="box">');

        //表示する
        $('body').append(box);
        requestAnimationFrame(()=> box.addClass('blue'));//アニメーション

    });
```

```css
   .box{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:tomato;
        transition: 3s;
    }

    .blue{
        background:skyblue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

本当はよろしくないけどDOMの読み込み準備が出来た後に`setTimeout`入れて処理。
特定の親DOMの変更を監視して自分でイベント作らないとキチンとはできないんじゃないかなぁ
関連：[jQuery 動的に読み込んだDOM要素の表示完了時にjQueryプラグインを適用したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27279/)

もしくは[jQueryのanimate関数](http://semooh.jp/jquery/api/effects/animate/params%2C+%5Bduration%5D%2C+%5Beasing%5D%2C+%5Bcallback%5D/)を使用するかだと思います

```js
$(function(){

    //要素をつくる
    var box = $('<div id="debug" class="box">');

    //表示する
    $('body').append(box);
    
    //boxの準備を待つ
    box.ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            box.addClass('blue');//アニメーション
        }, 10);
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:tomato;
    transition: 3s;
}

.blue{
    background:skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

[backgroundColorに対策しないといけないようですね。](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/)(ｼﾗﾅｶｯﾀ)

```js
//対策
(function(d){d.each(["backgroundColor","borderBottomColor","borderLeftColor","borderRightColor","borderTopColor","color","outlineColor"],function(f,e){d.fx.step[e]=function(g){if(!g.colorInit){g.start=c(g.elem,e);g.end=b(g.end);g.colorInit=true}g.elem.style[e]="rgb("+[Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((g.pos*(g.end[0]-g.start[0]))+g.start[0]),255),0),Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((g.pos*(g.end[1]-g.start[1]))+g.start[1]),255),0),Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((g.pos*(g.end[2]-g.start[2]))+g.start[2]),255),0)].join(",")+")"}});function b(f){var e;if(f&&f.constructor==Array&&f.length==3){return f}if(e=/rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(f)){return[parseInt(e[1]),parseInt(e[2]),parseInt(e[3])]}if(e=/rgb\(\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*\)/.exec(f)){return[parseFloat(e[1])*2.55,parseFloat(e[2])*2.55,parseFloat(e[3])*2.55]}if(e=/#([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/.exec(f)){return[parseInt(e[1],16),parseInt(e[2],16),parseInt(e[3],16)]}if(e=/#([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])/.exec(f)){return[parseInt(e[1]+e[1],16),parseInt(e[2]+e[2],16),parseInt(e[3]+e[3],16)]}if(e=/rgba\(0, 0, 0, 0\)/.exec(f)){return a.transparent}return a[d.trim(f).toLowerCase()]}function c(g,e){var f;do{f=d.css(g,e);if(f!=""&&f!="transparent"||d.nodeName(g,"body")){break}e="backgroundColor"}while(g=g.parentNode);return b(f)}var a={aqua:[0,255,255],azure:[240,255,255],beige:[245,245,220],black:[0,0,0],blue:[0,0,255],brown:[165,42,42],cyan:[0,255,255],darkblue:[0,0,139],darkcyan:[0,139,139],darkgrey:[169,169,169],darkgreen:[0,100,0],darkkhaki:[189,183,107],darkmagenta:[139,0,139],darkolivegreen:[85,107,47],darkorange:[255,140,0],darkorchid:[153,50,204],darkred:[139,0,0],darksalmon:[233,150,122],darkviolet:[148,0,211],fuchsia:[255,0,255],gold:[255,215,0],green:[0,128,0],indigo:[75,0,130],khaki:[240,230,140],lightblue:[173,216,230],lightcyan:[224,255,255],lightgreen:[144,238,144],lightgrey:[211,211,211],lightpink:[255,182,193],lightyellow:[255,255,224],lime:[0,255,0],magenta:[255,0,255],maroon:[128,0,0],navy:[0,0,128],olive:[128,128,0],orange:[255,165,0],pink:[255,192,203],purple:[128,0,128],violet:[128,0,128],red:[255,0,0],silver:[192,192,192],white:[255,255,255],yellow:[255,255,0],transparent:[255,255,255]}})(jQuery);

$(function(){

    //要素をつくる
    var box = $('<div class="box">');

    //表示する
    $('body').append(box);
    
    //boxの準備を待つ
    box.ready(function() {
        $(box).animate({ 
          "backgroundColor":"#87CEEB"
        }, 300 );//アニメーション
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:tomato;
    transition: 3s;
}

.blue{
    background:skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！animate()だと色のアニメーションができないようなのです。

Comment: @forest jQueryのanimateはカスタマイズしないと色使えないみたいですね。とりあえずそのバージョンも追記しておきます。

Comment: `box.ready`ですが、無意味であり非推奨です。公式のAPIドキュメントに解説されていますので一読してみてください。 https://api.jquery.com/ready/